# How can I import color schemes into Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, colors, color-scheme

I recently came across this website: http://studiostyles.info, which contains a list of color schemes that people have already created.

However, I can't find instructions on how to import them into Visual Studio 2010, does anyone know how?

*PS: I am sorry, if this question has been asked but I cannot find an answer, through search.*

Thanks Robert, this whole process was confusing here is the exact way to get to it:

```
Tools / Import and Export Settings / Import selected environment settings
/ Next / No, just import new settings, overwriting my current settings 
/ Next / Browse
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the menu bar:

```
Tools/Import and Export Settings
```